# Laravel 5.4 Eloquent Saving with relations hasMany

Tags: php, laravel-5, eloquent

I have the following Models, with hasMany and belongsTo relationship, i Would like to save many details of patrol, Patrol,insert successfully but the PatrolDetails does not insert any details in the database, 
**PATROL**

```
    <?php

class Patrol extends Model
{
    public function patrol_detail()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Patrol_Detail','patrol_id','id');
    }
}
```

**PATROL DETAILS**

```
 <?php

class PatrolDetail extends Model
{

    protected $fillable = ['full_name', 'organisation','position_grade'];

    public function patrol()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Patrol');
    }
}
```

**HERE MY CONTROLLER**

```
 public function store(Request $request)
    {
       // dd($request);
        $this->validate($request, [
            (validate)

        ]);
        $patrols = new Patrol();

        (patrols request)
        $patrols->save();

        for ($i=0; $i<count($request->full_name); $i++){
            $pd = new PatrolDetail;
            $pd->where('patrols_id',$patrols->id)->delete();
            if(empty($request->full_name[$i]) || empty($request->organisation[$i]) || empty($request->position_grade[$i])){
                session()->flash('error','All participant entries must be specified');
                $patrols->delete();
                return redirect()->back()->withInput();
                $pd->full_name = $request->full_name;
                $pd->organisation = $request->rganisation;
                $pd->position_grade = $request->position_grade;
            }
        }

        // redirect somewhere after
        if($patrols){
            return redirect()->route('patrol.index')
                ->with('successs' , 'created successfully');
        }
        return back()->withInput()->with('errors', 'Error creating  Details');

    }
```

**HERE IS MY VIEW**

```
    <td class="no">1</td>
   <td>
 <input type="text" class="full_name form-control  input-normal" name="full_name[]" value="">
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="organisation form-control input-normal" name="organisation[]" value="">
</td>
<td><input type="text" class="position_grade form-control input-normal" name="position_grade[]" value="">
 </td>
 <td>
```

When I save an Patrol, saves successfully, but the Patrol details dont save, any idea where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but i don't see "$pd->save()" in your code

Comment: i have added $pd->save(); $pd->patrol()->save($patrols); seems not saving still

Comment: Can u show me your code now? Another hand, the second line in the if block code should be PatrolDetail::where... and 3 last line after "return". All lines  of code after return will not work.

Comment: added $pd->save(); $pd->patrol()->save($patrols); after $pd->position_grade = $request->position_grade;

              

    
            }
        }

Comment: Ok as i said in the previous comment. All lines of code after"return" will not work. You should do all work you want before return

Comment: good so far but now giving this error htmlspecialchars() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given

Comment: So the problem resolved and this is another error. Does it log where the new error occur? I think that it should be come from the view files

Comment: This error often goes from view file where you use a blade echo like {{$object->property}} so i need you show your view file to help